# Avoid page reload when submitting form using ajax with laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I'm completely stuck trying to process a form submit using ajax instead of laravel to avoid page reload etc. But it isn't working and I don't know why. I've searched the wonderful web going through example after example but nothing seems to be working for me. This is the closest I can get. My knowledge is limited but my ambitions are high. Please take a moment and look through my code, beacuse I'm at the edge of mental breakdown right now.

Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ajax').submit(function(event){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'comments',
            data: $('form#ajax').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
        })

        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data); 
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

And here is my form in blade view:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'comments', 'id' => 'ajax')) }}
        {{ Form::hidden('parent_id', null) }}
        {{ Form::hidden('author', Auth::user()->username) }}
        {{ Form::textarea('content', null, array('placeholder' => 'Enter your comment here:', 'onfocus' => 'this.placeholder=""')) }}<br/>
        {{ Form::submit('Comment', array('class'=>'submit')) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

And here is my controller:

```
public function createComment() {
        //fixa här så man inte kan kommentera tom kommentar
        $validate = array('content' => 'required');

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $validate);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('comments')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::all());
        }
        else {
            $comment = new Comment();
            $comment->parent_id = Input::get('parent_id');
            $comment->author = Input::get('author');
            $comment->content = Input::get('content');
            $comment->save();  
        }
}

public function postComment() { 
    if(Request::ajax()) {
            $this->createComment();
            return Response::json(Input::all());
    }
}

public function getCommentsAndForm() {
        $comments = Comment::orderBy('id')->get();
        return View::make('comment')->with('comments', $comments);

}
```

And here is my routes:

```
Route::get('comments', array('uses' => 'CommentController@getCommentsAndForm'));

Route::post('comments', array('uses' => 'CommentController@postComment'));
```

When I submit the form it dissapears and nothing displays. If I remove `if(Request::ajax())` the comments get posted but the form still dissapears and instead of an empty page I get the posted comment in JSON. And when I reload the page the comments shows as I want to.
What is the problem? What am I doing wrong? I only want the posted comment to display above my form without reloading the page, is there a solution?

Comment: Since you are using done() in your js, i think you should also return a status code return Response::json(Input::all(),200);

Comment: @DimitrisKontoulis I tried what you said but still the same problem.

Comment: but you are doing nothing with the returned json. i can see that you are logging it in the console and nothing else.

Comment: @DimitrisKontoulis Ok, and what should I do with the returned json? It's beyond my knowledge.

Comment: you have to parse it and display it as you wish. right now you are getting a json object, you can't expect it to show in your html on its own :P

Comment: @DimitrisKontoulis Ok and how do I do that? I thought it was enough to submit it to the database and then get the data from the db and show it in html.

Comment: but how do you show it in html? at the moment you dont

Comment: @DimitrisKontoulis Check my updated answer, is that what you mean?

Comment: You don't get it. You are posting a comment with ajax. OK? the comment is stored in the db. You respond with a json object containing the comment data, but you do nothing with it in your view. You only conole.log() it. If you expect to show your comment you have to parse thee json object.
I just saw your update. I suppose this is in your coment-form view. if you wanna reload it to show the new comment you have to load it again, thats what i am saying, Even with ajax, or by refreshing the page. Else you parse the jsondata you receive and apend it on the contexts of the view

Comment: @DimitrisKontoulis I see, I'll try googling how to do that, thank you.

Comment: @DimitrisKontoulis Yes and I want to avoid the reload, and I can do this by somehow parsing the json object?

Comment: yes, if we asumme that you have a div with id="comment" , you could do in your js .done(function(data) {  $('#comment').html(data.content);
etc

Comment: @DimitrisKontoulis Ok I think I understand what you mean, I'll try this, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ajax').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'comments',
            data: $('form#ajax').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
        })

        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data); 
        });
        //just to be sure its not submiting form
        return false;
    });
});
```

the important here is to prevent form from submiting. You can try to change submit to button.