# Partial page reload using laravel and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to submit a form using `ajax` so my page will not do a `full page reload` rather only the form should change to show any errors. I have tried many options from the web with no luck. This [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592388/avoid-page-reload-when-submitting-form-using-ajax-with-laravel) is the best help I have seen, `but` it doesn't give the solution. `Note I am using laravel version 5.3.10`.

Here is my code:

`Javascript:`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#footer-form').click(function () {
            //event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/ensignhospital/mail',
                data: $('form#footer-form').serialize(),
                dataType: 'html'
            })

                    .done(function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    });

        });
    });

</script>
```

`Laravel Route:`

```
Route::group(['before' => 'guest'], function () {
    /*
     * CSRF Protection
     *
     * */
    Route::group(['before' => 'csrf'], function () {

        Route::post('/ensignhospital/mail', [
            'as' => 'mail',
            'uses' => 'HomeController@postSendMail'
        ]);
    });


});
```

`Laravel controller:`

```
 public function postSendMail(Request $request)
    {

        if($request->ajax()){

            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

                'first_name' => 'required',
                'last_name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'message' => 'required',
                'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha'
            ]);

            if($validator->fails()){
                return redirect()->back()
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput(Input::all());
            }else{
                return View('passed');

            }
        }else{
            return View('fail');
        }



    }
```

`Form:`

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'mail', 'method' => 'post', 'role' => 'form', 'id' => 'footer-form']) !!}
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    {!! Form::label('first_name', null, ['class' => 'sr-only']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('first_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'First Name']) !!}
    <i class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></i>
    @if($errors->has('first_name'))
        {{ $errors->first('first_name') }}
    @endif
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    {!! Form::label('last_name', null, ['class' => 'sr-only']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('last_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Last Name']) !!}
    <i class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></i>
    @if($errors->has('last_name'))
        {{ $errors->first('last_name') }}
    @endif
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    {!! Form::label('email', null, ['class' => 'sr-only']) !!}
    {!! Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Email address']) !!}
    <i class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback"></i>
    @if($errors->has('email'))
        {{ $errors->first('email') }}
    @endif
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    {!! Form::label('message', null, ['class' => 'sr-only']) !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('message', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => 8, 'placeholder' => 'Message']) !!}
    <i class="fa fa-pencil form-control-feedback"></i>
    @if($errors->has('message'))
        {{ $errors->first('message') }}
    @endif
</div>    

{!! Form::submit('Send', ['class' => 'btn btn-default', 'id' => 'mail_btn']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Use  location.reload(); on success

Comment: What does `.done(function (data) {console.log(data);});` show in the console ? I've noticed you are returning a view from your controller method, why don't you just return json data, which can be appended to the DOM via JS ?

Comment: @DavidDomain, I get an error from the `if($request->ajax()){}` block as I am directed to the error view `View('fail')`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to render the view that you want to pass throught the ajax like this:

```
return view('passed')->render();
```

...

```
return view('fail')->render();
```

**EDIT**

You have to pass `event` as a clouser parameter and uncomment this: `//event.preventDefault();`:

```
$('#footer-form').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/ensignhospital/mail',
            data: $('form#footer-form').serialize(),
            dataType: 'html'
        })

                .done(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });

    });
```

so that:

```
click(function () {
```

why it doesn't work. Should be:

```
click(function (event) {
```

Comment: my `ajax request` isn't even passing through the `if($request->ajax()){}` block. I am trying to have that `controller` catch the form data using ajax, hence preventing a total `page reload`.

Comment: When I get rid of the `if($request->ajax()){}` block the code `validates using laravel controller` but the `whole page reloads`.

Comment: Why have you comment this: `//event.preventDefault();` I will show you in edit

Comment: I noticed that the form did not post to the `url` so I removed it to make it do the default behaviour

Comment: I added the `event` variable but still won't pass into the `if block`